# Are partial type parameter applications possible in Java?

Tags: java, generics, language-agnostic

I know about Josh Bloch's [typesafe heterogeneous container](http://idlebrains.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/effective-java-typesafe-heterogeneous-container-pattern/):

```
<T> void container.put(Class<T>, T);
<T> T container.get(Class<T>);
```

I've also read about the Neal Gafter's ["Super" typesafe hetereogeneneous container](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html):

```
<T> void container.put(TypeToken<T>, T);
<T> T container.get(TypeToken<T>);
```

---

However, the following type of container has eluded me:

```
<T> void container.put(Foo<T>, Bar<T>);
<T> Bar<T> container.put(Foo<T>);
```

where `Foo` and `Bar` and any generic reference type.

Trying to write it out, you'd have to do something like:

```
// Setting T at the class level would force some fixed
// T or at best a bounded range of types
class Container<A, B/*, T */> {

    // So we can't have this:
    // Map<A<T>, B<T>> map = new HashMap<>();

    // And must do this (at the expense of type safety):
    Map<A<?>, B<?>> map = new HashMap<>();


    <T> void container.put(A<T> a, B<T> b) {
        map.put(a, b);
    } 

    <T> B<T> container.get(A<T> a) {
        // Not sure what to do here
    }
}
```

and then you'd be able to do something like:

```
// This doesn't compile because T is not specified and thus this is not actual Java:

class FooBarContainer extends Container<Foo, Bar, T> {   
   ...
}  

FooBarContainer container = new FooBarContainer();

// Can do this:
container.put(new Foo<String>(), new Bar<String>());
Bar<String> bar = container.get( /* some Foo<String> */ );

// Cannot do this:
container.put(new Foo<Long>(), new Bar<String>());
Bar<String> bar = container.get( /* some Foo<Long> */ );
```

But alas, that is not legal Java.

What I'm seeing here is that class-level generics are orthogonal to method-level generics. Is that the problem? If so, is there any way to reconcile that in Java?

Regardless, what do you need in a type systems that would allow such a container. What is the necessary feature called? If I had to name it, I'd call it partial type parameter application, but I'm sure this concept must exist in some general form that I don't know about.

Comment: Question is a little unclear, if you have a class with `A` and `B` type witnesses, if you pass `List<String>` (for example) as a type parameter then `A` would be a `List<String>`, not just a raw `List`. Unless I'm missing the question completely

Comment: Question: if you already know that A is a TypeToken or a Class, then why make A be a generic param of the `Container` class?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: `A` can be `TypeToken`, `Class` or `Foo`, so long as it's `TypeToken<T>`, `Class<T>`, or `Foo<T>` that are `map` keys.

Comment: @dimadima Understood. Generics cannot be used as A<T>. A must be a known type, such as TypeToken or Foo,  or a type that is either an ancestor or a descendant of a known type.

Comment: @Rogue yes you could do `List<String>` for `A` and `Foo<String>` for `B` but then you can't parameterize any further on `T` in the methods. You'd be stuck with `String`. I want to say "This container holds maps of `List<T>` and `Foo<T>`, where `T` is an invariant such that when you `put(A a, B b)`, the generic types of  `A` and `B` must match. This would be great.

Comment: @dimadima But maybe there exists some trick to get what you want. Intetesting question. Will post an answer if I find out something.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Class-level generics and method-level generics combine, they aren't orthogonal.

I see some options to solve what I think you are trying to do. But first, you must understand that you will not be able to declare a generic as a covariant of another generic, so you can't say:

```
class Container<A<B>> {}
```

because "A" is a type parameter and so has no associated type information, including whether it is a generic type itself. If you specify that "A" is a type that has a parameter then it can be done, such as:

```
class Container<A extends Foo<B>> {}
```

So for the first case, you could have an API such as this:

```
interface Container<KeyType, ValueType>
{
   void put(KeyType k, ValueType v);
   ValueType get(KeyType k);
}
```

which would allow concrete sub-types per key/value type (just a java.util.Map, really), such as:

```
interface StringContainer extends Container<String, String>
{
   void put(String k, String v);
   String get(String k);
}

interface FooBarContainer<C> extends Container<Foo<C>, Bar<C>>
{
   void put(Foo<C> k, Bar<C> v);
   Bar<C> get(Foo<C> k);
}
```

where all key/value pairs have the same KeyType and ValueType.

Adding method-level generics to the mix allows you to have KeyType and ValueType only correlate on the method invocation and not all invocations of the method:

```
interface VarContainer
{
   <VariantType> void put(Foo<VariantType> k, Bar<VariantType> v);
   <VariantType> Bar<VariantType> get(Foo<VariantType> k);
}
```

which allows variant key/value pairs within the same VarContainer:

```
VarContainer vc = ...
vc.put(new Foo<String>(), new Bar<String>());

vc.put(new Foo<Long>(), new Bar<Long>());
```

And this will give you the ability to specify your covariant type in concrete subclasses:

```
interface VarContainer<VariantType> extends Container<Foo<VariantType>, Bar<VariantType>>
{
   void put(Foo<VariantType> k, Bar<VariantType> v);
   Bar<VariantType> get(Foo<VariantType> k);
}
```

This other option only works if you know you have Foo and Bar in your container:

```
interface FooBarVarContainer
{
   <VariantType> void put(Foo<VariantType> k, Bar<VariantType> v);
   Bar<VariantType> get(Foo<VariantType> k);
}
```

and the container is now limited to Foo/Bar pairs, but can use the same variant type for an invocation of put on both arguments and on get between the argument and returned value:

```
FooBarVarContainer vc = ...
vc.put(new Foo<String>(), new Bar<String>()); // ok
vc.put(new Foo<String>(), new Bar<Long>()); // fails to compile
Bar<Long> = vc.get(new Foo<Long>()); // ok
```

Does this help give you what you need for your problem?

It also should be mentioned that putting mutable instances as keys into a map is not good practice since map keys should not only have properly implemented hashCode and equals methods but also once they are inserted the map would need to dynamically reindex as necessary if the keys changed. For example, if the hashCode values change, looking up that key in a hashmap in the future may fail or reach the wrong item.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Don't know why I didn't think of it this way. Will play with this the next time the opportunity arises.